# How to add dynamic counter for insert sql

Tags: php, postgresql

I would like to add a counter to show sequence of record inserted per query.

```
if(isset($_POST['keyword'])){
    $keyword = $_POST['keyword'];
    if($keyword){   
        foreach($keyword as $row){          
            $keyword_exe = $con->prepare("
                INSERT INTO t_theme(m_id,keyword,sequence_counter)VALUES('$id','$row', '???')
            ");
            $keyword_exe->execute();            
        }
    }
    }
```

I expect the output will be like this:

[image: postgresql_table]

Answer (score 0):

```
$counter = 0;
$pre_row = 0;
foreach($keyword as $row){   
   if( $pre_row  == $id){
       //In row m_id value equal to next value increase counter by 1
       $counter++;
   }else{
       //else start to 1
       $counter = 1;
       $pre_row = $id;
   }

    $keyword_exe = $con->prepare("
        INSERT INTO t_theme(m_id,keyword,sequence_counter)VALUES('$id','$row', '$counter')
    ");
    $keyword_exe->execute();            
}
```

[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/68tjQ)

Answer (score 0):

I didnt test with INSERT but you can use this when you SELECT

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY m_id ORDER BY id ASC) sequence_counter
```

For save some database space

[More here](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-row_number/)